# Как в HashMap можно сравнить все элементы карты с переменной?

Tags: java

Имеется HashMap

```
private Map<String, Socket> onlineUsers = new HashMap<String, Socket>();
```

Как мне его сравнить с любыми текстовым значением?

Comment: `String str="hello world";
boolean b=(onlineUsers ==str);`

А теперь серьёзно - чего ты хочешь. нормально объясни.

Comment: Имеется HashMap, мне необходимо сравнивать все элементы String hashmap на дубликаты и добавить их в другой HashMap

Answer (score 3):

> Имеется HashMap, мне необходимо
> сравнивать все элементы String hashmap
> на дубликаты и добавить их в другой
> HashMap

В HashMap не может быть дубликатов ключей по определению. Попробуй добавить в HashMap несколько объектов с  одинаковыми String ключами и убедишься что вставился только один.

[read](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/)

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/402912#402915 Вот я нашел ваш ответ, если нельзя так проверить, то как тогда проверять?

Comment: @AsmaRod, в ответе, который Вы нашли написано, что надо делать логин уникальным, чтобы нельзя было зарегистрировать дубликат. Например, делать запрос в БД и узнавать, есть такой пользователь уже или еще нет. 

Из этого постулата и плясать, собственно, если, конечно, у тебя эта проблема, а не другая. 

Вы пишите внятные вопросы и получите внятные ответы.